# facebook like and twitter follow button not displayed on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a wordpress plugin to ask the user to follow or like a facebook page in order to get a discount coupon . 
[plugin code on github](https://github.com/aouakki/PizzaPopup)

the code works just fine on the browser but when its opned on a mobile terminal it doesn't show : 
code for facebook

`<div class='fb-like' data-href='".$options['wppp_text_field_2']."' data-layout='button_count' "data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false"></div>;`

and the facebook API its well loaded. its working on the desktop/laptop browser .

Comment: FYI: Like Gating in any way, shape or form is not allowed by Facebook any more.

Comment: can you post a link to where it mentioned in the documentation ? and why its working normally on the desktop browser ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#properuse, 4.5, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

Comment: are you talking from a developer perspective or ethical perspective ?...because its working normally on my laptop browser . and Facebook allow tracking likes using : `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', ShowCoupon);`

Comment: They allow tracking, but they do not allow to reward people for liking a page in any way. It creates spam likes, that Facebook will remove when discovered, so anyone using your plugin would be putting themselves at risk of not only that, but also up to a block of their app id (assuming people will be using their own to use with your plugin), possibly even their account from registering any new apps.